# Request.IsAjaxRequest() == Request.IsMvcAjaxRequest()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Are these two the same essentially? I am just noticing that `Request.IsMvcAjaxRequest()` does not show up in my code hint as it does in the tutorial video [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/pdc2008/pc21). I am using ASP.net MVC 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ASP.NET MVC RC Release Notes](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=137661&clcid=0x409) states that IsMvcAjaxRequest is renamed to IsAjaxRequest. This means that you should just use IsAjaxRequest.

Quote from release notes:

> The IsMvcAjaxRequest
>   method been renamed to IsAjaxRequest.
>   As part of this change, the
>   IsAjaxRequest method was updated to
>   recognize the X-Requested-With HTTP
>   header. This is a well known header
>   sent by the major JavaScript libraries
>   such as Prototype.js, jQuery, and
>   Dojo. The ASP.NET AJAX helpers were
>   updated to send this header in
>   requests. However, they continue to
>   also send it in the body of the form
>   post in order to work around the issue
>   of firewalls that strip unknown
>   headers.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks.